# How to call code behind function from label.text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, code-behind

I am trying to call a function defined in code behind from Label.Text but it's not working. Here is the code...
code in .aspx file

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# GetPagingCaptionString() %>' ID="pagenumberLabel"></asp:Label>
```

code block from code behind

```
public string GetPagingCaptionString()
        {
            int currentPageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtHidden.Value);
            int searchOrderIndex;
            if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Session["searchOrderIndex"]), out searchOrderIndex))
            {
                return string.Format("{0} to {1} orders out of {2}", (currentPageNumber * 20) + 1,
                    (currentPageNumber + 1) + 20, GetItemsCount(searchOrderIndex.ToString()));
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here.

Comment: Is the `label` within something like a `<asp:Repeater>` or `<asp:GridView>`?  I ask because you're using `<%#`.  If not, then you'll have to define the `.Text` in the code-behind

Comment: When do you call that method? when you do GridView.DataBind() ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're using a template based control (such as `<asp:Repeater>` or `<asp:GridView>`) then you can't use inline code-blocks such as you have within a server-side control.

In other words, you can't have `<%=%>` blocks within the attributes of server-side controls (such as `<asp:Label>`). The code will not be run and you will find the code is actually sent as part of the rendered HTML.  The exception is for databinding controls where `<%#%>` code-blocks *are* allowed.

You're better off in this situation setting the `.Text` property in the code-behind itself.

For instance in your page-load function....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    pagenumberLabel.Text = GetPagingCaptionString();
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome - I only found this out myself the hard-way... good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Property to your page it will be accessible from your aspx like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= PagingCaptionString %>' ID="pagenumberLabel" />
```

**NB** `<%= %>` tag rather than `<%# %>` which is used for databinding controls

**Codebehind:**

```
public string PagingCaptionString {
    get {
        int currentPageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtHidden.Value);
        int searchOrderIndex;
        if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Session["searchOrderIndex"]), out searchOrderIndex))
        {
            return string.Format("{0} to {1} orders out of {2}", (currentPageNumber * 20) + 1,
                (currentPageNumber + 1) + 20, GetItemsCount(searchOrderIndex.ToString()));
        }
        return String.Empty;
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it is showing error like

This is not scriptlet. This will be shown as plaintext.

Comment: @Abhash786 - that is because you can't have `<%=%>` code-blocks within the attributes of server-side controls.  See my answer