# Calling function for file uploader

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, file-upload

I want to hide file upload control behind label I found solution for that on this link:
 
[Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

There was a link to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/


Now by clicking on label it open file uploader and after uploading file it hides file upload tab, but I want to save file uploaded by that uploader in database throuh a function in `aspx.cs` file. 
How may I call that function?

This link did't help for me
[How to call code behind function from label.text in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305340/how-to-call-code-behind-function-from-label-text-in-asp-net)
using file uploader in label is just for styling.

Here is my function that I want to call

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!inputfile.HasFile)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "isActive", "Test();", true);
            //Response.Write("No file Selected"); return;
        }
        else
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(inputfile.PostedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            string contentType = inputfile.PostedFile.ContentType;

            HttpPostedFile file = inputfile.PostedFile;
            byte[] document = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(document, 0, file.ContentLength);
            /*  Stream fs = inputfile.PostedFile.InputStream;
              BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
              Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);*/
            if ((extension == ".pdf") || (extension == ".doc") || (extension == ".docx") || (extension == ".xls")
                || (extension == ".pptx"))//extension  
            {
                if (file.ContentLength <= 31457280)//size  
                {
                    FYPEntities2 obj = new FYPEntities2();
                    tblFile us = new tblFile();
                    us.Name = filename;
                    us.ContentType = contentType;
                    us.Data = document;
                    //  us.Data = bytes;
                    us.Date = DateTime.Now;
                    obj.tblFiles.Add(us);
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "alert('Hello World');", true);
                    obj.SaveChanges();
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                }
                else
                {

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "isActive", "filesize();", true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "isActive", "invalidformat();", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Put a LinkButton on the page and give it no Text, so it is not visible for the user but does still exists.

```
<style>
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-file-upload {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<label for="<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload">Custom Upload</i>
</label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then in code behind attach an `onchange` attribute to `FileUpload1` with the `UniqueID` of `LinkButton1`. When the upload changes, javascript will file the PostBack event of the LinkButton thus automatically uploading the file.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "__doPostBack('" + LinkButton1.UniqueID + "','')");
}
```

Comment: my question is to call a function for storing uploaded file

Comment: I want to call Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) when user uploads a file

Comment: You can add a button that handles the Click, or do you mean something different?

Comment: I cant place fil upload control inside a button

Comment: You want to start upload immediately after selecting a file perhaps? Not clicking another button?

Comment: Updated my anwer.